# How can I get the Edit Menu to appear in a UIWebView with contentEditable?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, contenteditable

I have an iPad App with an embedded Text Editor. The editor is a UIWebView with `contenteditable` set to `true`. The form also contains a simple text field for the title of the document.

If the user types in the title, then taps **Return** they can enter text in WebView, and tap-and-hold to get the magnifying glass and then the edit menu.

If, however, the user enters the title, and then **taps** on the web view they can enter text, tap-and-hold to get the magnifying glass, but the edit menu never appears.

The only difference I can see is that in the first case the `textFieldShouldReturn:` method fires first, and then the `textFieldDidEndEditing:` method fires, while in the second case only the `textFieldDidEndEditing:` method fires.

Here are the two methods in question:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

and

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    NSString *js = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementById('theBody').setAttribute('contenteditable','true')"];
    [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:js];
    [self.webView becomeFirstResponder];
    [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].focus()"];
}
```

Does anyone have any idea what the difference is, and how I can get the edit menu to appear?

Comment: the same problem here! :), any news? I believe it is an iOs bug, if you have multiple lines written in the web view, the menu items should appear. this happens in iOS 7 only, menu items appear ok in iOS 6

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is an iOS 7 bug, try adding the following code to your view controller as a workaround.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
     self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
     //Additional inicialization code.
}
```

Note that property is available on iOS 7 or later.
Hope this helps!

Comment: I can confirm that this workaround fixed the issue in my case on iOS 7.1. The menu would only show if there was more than one line of text in the DOM text area. The issue appears to have some additional subtleties, since it could also be remedied by moving the text element to another place in the DOM. It looks like the menu is showing, but that UIWebView makes some bad placement calculations and it ends up somewhere out-of-frame.